# Python - How do i sort this by X, Y coordinates

Tags: python, regex, sorting

I want to know how do i sort the below by its X Y coordinates.
the below array (coords) gives me an output in this manner...

> - 220x600+200+300
> - 200x300+400+500

i want to sort by the last 2 digits:
200+300 are X and Y coords
400+500 are X and Y coords

i want it to be sorted in this manner... first by Y then by X similiar to below
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]

Please let me know if its achievable.  Below is a snippet of my code... its important that i dont modify the array list (coords), just sort it by the way i explained above

```py
coords = re.findall(r"(\d+[xX]\d+\+\d+\+\d+)", component_list, re.IGNORECASE)

for coord in coords[1:]:
    resolution = re.search(r"(\d+[xX]\d+)", coord, re.IGNORECASE)
    resolution = resolution.group(1)
    coord = re.search(r"(\d+\+\d+)", coord, re.IGNORECASE)
    coord = coord.group(1)
```

Comment: Would you be able to show what `component_list` is initially and what the expected output is? If it's huge, please offer a snippet that covers the necessary cases and the corresponding output. Thanks.

Comment: the component_list is a command that outputs 200x600+200+300 blah blah blah;  the output is in the list above 220x600+200+300 <<<<< this is the output

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the exact structure? Having me guess what it is makes it difficult to reproduce your code and validate that the solution I'm giving you actually makes sense for your use case. Please see [mcve]. For one, it's confusing because `findall` operates on strings, so `component_list` is not an actual list. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

i was able to resolve the issue myself.. just in case anyone needs an answer to this below is what i used.. i created the below function and then used that funciton in sorted()

```py
        def sort_by_coord(x):
            coord = re.search(r"\+(\d+\+\d+)", x, re.IGNORECASE)
            coord_cut = "{}".format(coord.group(1)).split('+')
            return [coord_cut[1], coord_cut[0]]

        coords = re.findall(r"(\d+[xX]\d+\+\d+\+\d+)", component_list, re.IGNORECASE)
        coords = sorted(coords, key=sort_by_coord)
```